# Issue migrating to material ui v5 using datepicker and next

Tags: material-ui, next.js

Getting Module not found: Can't resolve 'luxon' when using LocalizationProvider with AdapterLuxon and Next

I'm hoping I have something setup incorrectly.

codesandbox with the issue:
https://codesandbox.io/s/package-test-chyxlo?file=/pages/index.js

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was reading the docs wrong. Mui provides the adapters out of the box but you still need to include the utility package that you want. In my case, luxon.